# Display Image From External Server - Phonegap

Tags: cordova

Ok so I'm creating a phonegap app where the user is able to have a profile image. I have the images saved in an external location than the phonegap project.

The problem I'm having is that when I open the profile page on my normal computer browser (localhost:3000/profile.html) the image shows like normal:

[image]

But whenever I run the project using the Phonegap Developer App the image doesn't show up:

[image]

I added the following to the config.xml file:

```
<access origin="http://localhost:80" />
```

Which, from what I read, should allow the image to show. This line, in the xml file, helped me view the image in the normal computer browser, without it the image woudn't show up in neither the computer or the cellphone. Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something? This is my first time making a phonegap app so any help is greatly appreciated.

PD: I'm saving the images in http://localhost/phonegap/images

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but are you trying to reach your laptop from your smartphone via http://localhost? This will work on your laptop as it refers to the laptop. Won't work on your phone as localhost refers to your phone there.

Comment: LOL that is true, can't believe I didn't think of that sooner. Sorry for the question, but I guess we all have our moments. Anyways it solved my problem. Thanks! haha

Comment: @Phonolog you should write the answer to mark it as answered.

Comment: Haha I'm glad it helped anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localhost refers to *this* device, so you will not be able to access your laptop from your phone via htttp://localhost, while it works on your laptop.